# how can i calculate date not less than 18

Tags: php

I am trying to find the date not less than 18 years, I tried this following code, but its not working for me.

```
// validate birthday
function validateAge($then, $min)
{
    // $then will first be a string-date
    $then = strtotime($then);

    echo "<br>";
    echo 'test1-';
    var_dump( $then );

    exit;
    //The age to be over, over +18
    $min = strtotime('+18 years', $then);

    if(time() < $min)  {
        die('Not 18'); 
    }
}

$res = validateAge('2016-02-29', $min = 18);

var_dump($res);
```

I fyou see the above question, you can see that, date is not valid, even if i pass the wrong date, its shows the $then = strtotime($then);

var_dump($then) show the int

my question is, how its printing the timestamp, event if we passing the invalid date.

Comment: If you look at the lines you've written, you'll find out why it doesn't work, easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating number of years between 2 dates in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387166/calculating-number-of-years-between-2-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is correct. Remove die, exit and echo which is not needed

```
function validateAge($then, $min)
{
    // $then will first be a string-date
    $then = strtotime($then);

    //The age to be more then min years
    $min = strtotime('+'. $min . ' years', $then);

    return time() > $min;
}

$res = validateAge('2016-02-29', $min = 18);
echo $res ? 'O\'key' : "Not $min years";
```

[demo](https://eval.in/570602)

Comment: I probably searched too complicated. :s

Comment: I downvoted because this is not a question to be answered. Instead, it's better to vote for close.

Comment: @revo it's your right, but i think that in this case more orrect to downvote question and vote to close it. While rewardeding an answer is independent process

Comment: @splash58 It's community right and yes, I downvoted both.

Comment: even if i pass the wrong date, its shows the $then = strtotime($then);

var_dump($then) show the int

my question is, how its printing the timestamp, event if we passing the invalid date.

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe something like this

```
function compareAge($date,$min=18)
{
    $strdate = strtotime($date);
    $curdate = strtotime("today");
    $datefin=date("Ymd",$curdate)-date("Ymd",$strdate);
    $age=substr($datefin,0,strlen($datefin)-4);
    return $age>=$min;
}

var_dump(compareAge("2013-05-13"));
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7bf9e5e9e9765074d3fd56da5b66ca5b8553ef6)

Answer (score 0):

you could use this method:

```
public function validateAge($then)
{
  $then= date_create($then);
  $now = date_create("now");

  $diff = $now->diff($then);

  if ($diff->y > 18)
  {
  die('not 18');
  }

}
```

Duplicate:
[Calculating number of years between 2 dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387166/calculating-number-of-years-between-2-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

use the datetime object to save all sorts of pain. Its so much more simple.

```
function validateAge(DateTime $then, $min = 18)
{
    $now = new DateTime();

    $minimum = clone($now);         // you could just modify now, but this is simpler to explain
    $minimum->modify("-$min years");


    if($then < $minimum) {
        return false;
    } 

    return true;
}

echo validateAge(new DateTime('1-1-1997')) ? 'true' : 'false';  // returns false
echo validateAge(new DateTime('1-1-1999')) ? 'true' : 'false';  // returns true
```

see [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/558f043a7396b181f1e7fbf2710da9a423b1270e)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, so many try-hards.
In case you like is simple:

```
<?php
function validateAge($date) {
    return date_create('18 years ago') > date_create($date);
}

var_dump(
    validateAge('2010-10-05'),
    validateAge('1992-09-02')
);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

[Play with me on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/GVUDQ#tabs)

**Edit:** Also works with the $min parameter:

```
<?php
function validateAge($date, $min) {
    return date_create("$min years ago") > date_create($date);
}

var_dump(
    validateAge('2010-10-05', 18),
    validateAge('1992-09-02', 18)
);
```