# I want to create a specified year in anniversary format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to print a year in 21st, 22nd, 23rd, 24th so on

suppose today echo=21st
next year would be changed to 22nd

let's say suppose original date is 2012 and today is 2019 it would show 6th year of publication

```
<?
Orginal date=1996
today date=fetch current year
echo= today is 22nd year";
?>
```

Example:

```
<font face = "Oswald" size ="3">21<sup><small>ST</small></sup>  Year of publication</font>

<font face = "Oswald" size ="3">21<sup><small>ST</small></sup>  Year of publication</font>
```

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: Honestly you need to slow it down a bit and write your question properly. Your title also says `create` twice.

Comment: HERE YOU GO  I NEED TO FETCH ANNUM FROM CURRENT YEAR WHICH WILL BE ALREADY PROVIED

Comment: Break your problem down in to steps and research them. Eg, [How to get the number of years between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387166/calculating-number-of-years-between-2-dates-in-php), and [How to add ordinals to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/display-numbers-with-ordinal-suffix-in-php)

Comment: IM NOT SHOUTING I BROKE MY CAPS KEY

Comment: Then hold shift.

Comment: its example suppose today is 2019 it would be 1st year

Comment: suppose original date is 2012 and today is 2019 it would show 6th year

Comment: @UzairJan You have to show us what you have tried!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/display-numbers-with-ordinal-suffix-in-php

Comment: updated plz see

Comment: @UzairJan Your code don't really look like an attempt, but more just a display of the logic.

Comment: im giving example, logic man, instead correcting on logic i want functional code

Comment: @UzairJan StackOverflow is not a coding service, You have to try yourself, and if you face a problem when you HAVE tried, then we can help you

Comment: *its example suppose today is 2019 it would be 1st year*. **Ok so the original year is year 1. Fine.** *suppose original date is 2012 and today is 2019 it would show 6th year.* **What?? If 2012 is 1 according to the previous comment then 2019 should be 7?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is PHP Code**

```
<?php
function get_year_of_publication($date) {
$now = new DateTime();
$date_of_publication = new DateTime($date);
$difference = $now->diff($date_of_publication)->y;
return $difference + 1;}
function ordinalise($number, $locale = 'en_US') {
$formatter = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);
return $formatter->format($number);}
$publication_dates = ['1999-01-01'];
foreach ($publication_dates as $date) {
$year_of_publication = get_year_of_publication($date);
$ordinalised = ordinalise($year_of_publication);}
$dt=preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i',$ordinalised);
$str_upper = $dt[1];
?>
```

**Here is HTML Output**

```
 <font face = "Oswald" size ="3"><?php echo $dt[0]; ?><sup><small><?php echo strtoupper($str_upper); ?></small></sup> Year of publication  </font>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, you are looking for something along these lines:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$date_of_publication = new DateTime('2015-03-12');

// Calculate the difference in number of years
$difference = $now->diff($date_of_publication)->y;

// Add one to the difference in years
$difference += 1;

// Now we have the difference, we can add relevant ordinal
// PHP 5.3.0+ has a nice built in function
$locale = 'en_US'; // Set this to whatever locale you are using or based on the locale of the user
$formatter = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);

$ordinalised = $formatter->format($difference);

echo $ordinalised; // 5th
```

Combining this with your HTML will look something like the following:

**Note**: The `font` tag is not supported in HTML5, I have replaced with a `span`.

```
function get_year_of_publication($date) {

    $now = new DateTime();
    $date_of_publication = new DateTime($date);

    // Calculate the difference in number of years
    $difference = $now->diff($date_of_publication)->y;

    // Add one to the difference in years and return it
    return $difference + 1;

}


function ordinalise($number, $locale = 'en_US') {

    $formatter = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::ORDINAL);

    return $formatter->format($number);

}


$publication_dates = ['2015-03-12', '2016-01-08', '2019-06-07'];

foreach ($publication_dates as $date) {

    $year_of_publication = get_year_of_publication($date);
    $ordinalised = ordinalise($year_of_publication);

    echo "<span>{$ordinalised}</span><br />";

}
```

See the following answers for a more detailed description:

- [Display numbers with ordinal suffix in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109978/display-numbers-with-ordinal-suffix-in-php)
- [Calculating number of years between 2 dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387166/calculating-number-of-years-between-2-dates-in-php)

Comment: it work but i want in  this format 

<font face = "Oswald" size ="3">21<sup><small>ST</small></sup>  Year of publication</font>

Comment: Why do you want to use the deprecated font tag?  The function pre-styles the text for you in the way in which you want it displayed i.e. no need for sup and small tags